# Adding dimensions using numpy.reshape()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a situation I'm trying to resolve. I have climate model data in an array with 480 monthly entries at the latitude and longitude grid points of this model (the particulars are irrelevant). That is, I have a numpy array with dimensions (480, lat, lon).

I need to create yearly averages at each spatial grid point. The way I would *like* to do this is by using `numpy.reshape()` to make a 4D array with dimensions (480/12, 12, lat, lon) (where I group the timesteps into groups of 12 and restack them, as it were). Then I would average along the second axis (`np.mean(dat_new, axis = 1)`).

The whole thing would be

```
dat_new = np.reshape(dat, (dat.shape[0]/12, 12, dat.shape[1], dat.shape[2]))
dat_annual_mean = np.mean(dat_new, axis = 1)
```

My question is: does reshape work this way? Would it rearrange things in the correct order? If not (or even if so) is there another (potentially less clumsy way to do this?)

Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me, except I would use : `dat.shape[0]//12` or simply `-1` there to let it decide the remaining length.

Comment: Experiment with a small array where you can see the layout of values, e.g. `arr = np.arange(6*2).reshape(6,2,1)`.  Does a `reshape(3,2,2,1)` look right?

Comment: @hpaulj no, it doesn't, but honestly just pointing out that it doesn't work without suggesting an alternative doesn't really help me

Comment: We are trying to figure out what kind of arrangement you want.  If reshaping doesn't do the job, you may need to transpose/swap axes.  But without a concrete example we are just guessing.

Comment: If I understand it right, you have an array of shape (480, 3), that is 480 measurements of a data point and associated latitude and longitude.   Or do you have a perfect grid of lat/long combinations?

Comment: It looks like he's just manipulating the 1st dimension.  Whether it has 1 or 2 additional dimensions doesn't matter.  They shouldn't change with this manipulation.

Comment: I have an array of shape (480, lat, lon), let's say 144 for each just to have numbers there. So (480, 144, 144). I want to take the first 12 'slices' in the first dimension and stack them. Then the second 12, etc. So I'd end up with (40, 12, 144, 144), so if I average over the second dimension I would get annual averages at each (lat, lon) grid point (for each of 40 years).

Answer (score 0):

You should first permute the dimensions so that your data is reshaped in the correct order.

```
dat_new=np.reshape(np.transpose(dat,(1,2,0)),
                   (dat.shape[1],dat.shape[2],dat.shape[0]//12, 12))
dat_annual_mean = np.mean(dat_new, axis = 3)
```

i.e. it will give you an array with dimensions (lat, lon, 480/12), which you can transpose further if necessary.

Comment: What are the properties of numpy.reshape() that let you know that this will work? I don't see how the transposition helps.

Comment: The default assumption for reshape is C-like index order, so that the last index changes the fastest. I assumed your 480 samples are distributed so that (lat,lon,0...39) correspond to Jan, (lat,lon,40..79) to Feb, etc. If you have doubts, maybe prepare a test array, where you know the result.

Comment: I just looked at the documentation of reshape, your original code should also work if you add order='F' as an option to reshape, which gives you Fortran order, where the first index changes the fastest.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your latest post above before. Now that I understood your data better I guess the (new) upper code is correct. Anyway, I would recommend you to understand/read how multi-dimensional arrays are ordered, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified so we can see the whole array, this is what I think you are trying to do:

```
In [608]: arr = np.zeros((3*4,2),int)
In [609]: arr[:,0]=np.arange(12)
In [610]: arr
Out[610]: 
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 2,  0],
       [ 3,  0],
       [ 4,  0],
       [ 5,  0],
       [ 6,  0],
       [ 7,  0],
       [ 8,  0],
       [ 9,  0],
       [10,  0],
       [11,  0]])
In [611]: arr.reshape(3,4,2)
Out[611]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 1,  0],
        [ 2,  0],
        [ 3,  0]],

       [[ 4,  0],
        [ 5,  0],
        [ 6,  0],
        [ 7,  0]],

       [[ 8,  0],
        [ 9,  0],
        [10,  0],
        [11,  0]]])
In [612]: _.mean(axis=1)
Out[612]: 
array([[ 1.5,  0. ],
       [ 5.5,  0. ],
       [ 9.5,  0. ]])
```